# How can I keep track of the smallest entry in a collection?

Tags: collections, rust

I have a toy app where I can add entries to a collection, but I cannot modify the `add` method to keep track of the smallest entry.

The basic version is [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=685d31e4bf43684add58951528c42177)

I think I need to add something like a `smallest_entry: Option<&'a Entry>` to the `struct` that holds the entries, but I cannot figure out how to modify the `add_entry`

the data structure is

```rust
struct Entry {
    pub value: usize,
}

struct Source {
    pub entries: Vec<Entry>,
    // pub smallest_entry: Option<&'a Entry>,
}

struct SourcesRepository {
    pub map: HashMap<String, Source>,
}
```

and the current `add_entry` method is

```rust
impl SourcesRepository {
    fn add_entry(&mut self, title: String, entry: Entry) {
        match self.map.get_mut(&title) {
            Some(source) => {
                // we already have a Source for this title: add new entry to it
                source.entries.push(entry);
            }
            None => {
                // no source existing for this title: create new and add entry
                let mut source = Source {
                    entries: Vec::new(),
                };
                source.entries.push(entry);
                self.map.insert(title, source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I imagine once I have the `source` entry I should compare it with the `smallest_entry` and update that reference if the new entry is smaller. I've tried to modify the code but I cannot make the lifetimes work.

```rust
impl SourcesRepository<'_> {
    fn add_entry(&mut self, title: String, entry: Entry) {
        match self.map.get_mut(&title) {
            Some(source) => {
                // we already have a Source for this title: add new entry to it
                match source.smallest_entry {
                    Some(smallest_entry) => {
                        if entry.value < smallest_entry.value {
                            source.smallest_entry = Some(&entry);
                        }
                    }
                    None => {
                        source.smallest_entry = Some(&entry);
                    }
                }

                source.entries.push(entry);
            }
            None => {
                // no source existing for this title: create new and add entry
                let mut source = Source {
                    entries: Vec::new(),
                    smallest_entry: Some(&entry),
                };
                source.entries.push(entry);
                self.map.insert(title, source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[link to broken version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6a6b6008770c9b01f7483d9e635d0af4)

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct

For your specific case though, you can store the index of the smallest entry instead of using a reference to circumvent the problems.

Comment: [The duplicates applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9e603fe599c91bb6f71c3f2f0995b43e)